# URL Rewriting is showing 404 Error after Upgrading Framework from 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have just change framework of my website from 2.0 to 4.0. And I am getting error HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found whenever I try to open URL Rewriting webpage.
It was working fine at a time of Framework 2.0, don't know what is the wrong now. I have google many things but din't get any proper solution.
Please help me to solve the problem.

**My Code is as below :**

```
http://www.theprojectjugaad.com/PlacementAssistance.html -> Not Working
http://www.theprojectjugaad.com/PlacementAssistance.aspx -> Working
```

**Global.asax :**

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes();
    }

    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs ex)
    {
        if (!Request.Url.Host.Equals("localhost")
            && !Request.Url.Host.ToString().Contains("www.theprojectjugaad.com")
            && Request.Url.Host.ToString().Contains("theprojectjugaad.com"))
        {
            string Result = string.Concat(
            "http://",
            Request.Url.Authority.Replace("theprojectjugaad.com", "www.theprojectjugaad.com"),
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier(Request.Path),
            Request.Url.Query);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Result, true);
        }
    }

    private static void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(
                "PlacementAssistance", new System.Web.Routing.Route("PlacementAssistance.html",
                                    new RouteHandler("~/PlacementAssistance.aspx")));
    }
```

**RouteHandler.cs :**

```
    public RouteHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        _virtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var display = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(
                        _virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as IDisplay;
        return display;
    }

     string _virtualPath;
```

**IDisplay.cs :**

```
public interface IDisplay : IHttpHandler
{

}
```

**web.config :**

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <remove name="Plesk. SEO-safe redirect for http://www.theprojectjugaad.com" />
        <rule name="Plesk. SEO-safe redirect for http://www.theprojectjugaad.com" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.theprojectjugaad.com" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
          </conditions>
          <serverVariables />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://theprojectjugaad.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: What happens if you step through the code? What happens where it is supposed to rewrite? Do you get an error message?

Comment: If I am running it through VS2010 then It is working fine. But If I am using it on IIS or on Server then It is showing 404 Error.

Comment: Maybe a long shot, but what mode does the applicationpool run as? Classic or integrated (try switching)? Which IIS version? What changes have you made besides changing the target framework?

Comment: @scheien, I changed application pool from classic to Integrated and It started working. :)

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working :-)

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL that is not working?

What I see is you've corrected the URL from .html to .aspx and it works.

Comment: It is dotnet so its main extension is .aspx, by using URL rewriting, I am opening it as .html